# How to return an action from a function?

Tags: c#, wpf, func

I am new to this (and nothing I've read or tried has worked).

I wish to use a function of form:

```
 Func<string, Action> getAction = (editingmark) =>
    {
        Action doit;
        switch (editingmark)
        {
            case ">":
                doit = editRx;    <--ERROR OCCURS HERE.
                break;
        }
        return doit;
    };
```

where editRx has the form:

```
Action editRx = () =>
    {
    };
```

and I get:

*A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property ...editRx*

What to do? (and is there a better way?)

Thanks for all help.

Comment: Maybe `editRx` is out of scope?

Comment: mark the `editRx` as `static`

Comment: Most likely you are declaring the `Func` inside static method and Action is declared for instance.

Comment: @RohitVats  Error occurs at "doit=editRx".

Comment: @Alan - Post the complete code.

Comment: @RohitVats Umm..I don't know where to go from here (this is the complete code).

Comment: @YuliamChandra That fixes it. Is there anyway to avoid a "static" declaration?

Comment: @Alan - p.s.w.g's answer is correct one. You cannot use an instance variable to initialize another instance variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to initialize `getAction` as a field, like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    Action editRx = () =>
    {
    };
    Func<string, Action> getAction = (editingmark) =>
    {
        Action doit = null;
        switch (editingmark)
        {
            case ">":
                doit = editRx;
                break;
        }
        return doit;
    };
}
```

The problem here is that you're trying to make initialize `getAction` with a closure around `editRx`, but you can't do this in a field initializer. Try putting this inside your constructor instead:

```
public class Foo
{
    Action editRx = () =>
    {
    };
    Func<string, Action> getAction;

    public Foo()
    {
        this.getAction = (editingmark) =>
        {
            Action doit;
            switch (editingmark)
            {
                case ">":
                    doit = editRx;
                    break;
            }
            return doit;
        };
    }
}
```

Also note that using delegates like this is a little bit unconventional for C#. It's likely you can refactor this to a regular method or other OOP construct and make your code a significantly more clear and understandable. Once you get your code *working* I recommend you ask on [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) about how you can reorganize your code into something more idiomatic.

Comment: The above code resides in a Base class to be inherited. The editRx method will do different things depending on the child of the inheritance. I was thinking this would be the easiest approach. Is there a better one?

Comment: @AlanWayne Probably with [override methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Check out this, please

```
Func<string, Action> getAction = (editingmark) =>
{
    Action doit = null;
    switch (editingmark)
    {
        case ">":
            doit = editRx;
            break;
    }
    return doit;
};
static readonly Action editRx = () =>
{
};
```